# New To Coding. Can anyone assist me?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a word counter and I just cant seem to get it. Can anyone help?

```
import re
print("Welcome To This Software Made By Aaron!")
word = raw_input("Enter Your Words: ")
Check = 0
Right = 0
Length = len(word)
while True:
    if Right == 1:
        if Length < Check:
            Check = Check + 1
            print(Check)
    if Length == Check:
        Right = 1

print("Your Word Count Is " +Check)
```

Comment: Learning to code takes time, and Stack Overflow is unfortunately not the good place. Stack Overflow is more about answering specific technical questions once you know the basics, rather than a teaching platform. You should check out http://www.codecademy.com/ and little by little understand the important concepts. In your specific case, your `while` loop doesn't terminate. You need to do something like `while Check<Length:` instead.

Comment: On a different point -- variable names with capital letters are contrary to standard practice for Python. See the style guide at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

As that guy said, learning to code takes time, if you are starting you must try to avoid libraries that do all the work for you, like "length" . 
In this case you are trying to make your own "length", so doesn't make sense to use it. Something like "for" will work perfect

```
word    = raw_input("Enter Your Words: ")
x  = True
counter = 0

for w in word:
    counter = counter + 1 

print("Your Word Count Is " +counter)
```

Take a look to [CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python) Python's course

Answer (score 0):

First, I see no need to import the `re` module, as there's no usage of regular expression functions in your code.

You're clearly using Python 3, so replace `raw_input()` with `input()`.

Finally, your while loop has no breaks, so it'll be an infinite loop. Think about what you wish to accomplish, and put an appropriate `break` statement in there. Or you can use a for loop instead - should be better in this case actually.

Comment: You do know that Python 2 supports `print()`, right?